# React doesn't re-render if variable is inside of a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDay() + count);

  function handleCount() {
    setCount((cCount) => cCount + step);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setStep((cStep) => cStep - 1)}>-</button>
        <span>Step : {step}</span>
        <button onClick={() => setStep((cStep) => cStep + 1)}>+</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleCount}>-</button>
        <span>Count: {count}</span>
        <button onClick={handleCount}>+</button>
      </div>
      <span>{date.toDateString()}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

if I set like that when I trigger `handleCount` `{date.toDateString()}` this part will re render but if i move setDate Function inside handleCount like below it won't re render why this happening

```
function handleCount() {
    date.setDate(date.getDay() + count);
    setCount((cCount) => cCount + step);
  }
```

Comment: `date.toDateString()` does not ger rerendered because `date` is not a state but a normal variable.

Comment: i know but if i use date.setDate(date.getDay() + count) function out of the handleCount it is rerendering

Comment: In your working code, calling `setCount()` causes your component to rerender, which means `App` executes again, but this time with the value of `count` you had just set, allowing `date` to be set correctly. When you set `date` inside of your callback function, your date variable gets reset to `new Date()` upon the rerender and renders this value.

Comment: @NickParsons i got exatcly thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

date.toDateString() does not re-rendered because date is not a state but a normal variable.

React component will re-render if state changes. To make it re-render when date changes, you need to add it as state. Also, in first case, the date is set every time the render function is called and that variable is used directly in JSX. The variable inside function is different.